# Socket destroyed or timeout while reading data

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am writing an socket client at the moment.

Writing on the socket works perfectly.

But when i try to read the data with BufferedReader it hangs.

Sometimes it works but the mostly the socket is destroyed by the (device?).

(I only see this at the Server Side: +WIND:62:Socket Client Gone:172.20.237.2, which means Client is gone/closed socket)

I tried:

```
- first i used readNewLine, it worked but slowly so i tought this was 
blocking.
- then i tried Char by Char but this is also blocking at: br.read i think.
- i tried to set Socket Timeot to 100000 e.g.
- i changed port (80,3067, now 6660)
```

i dont know why its so slow its only connection from Wifi-Module (with Socketlistener) to Android-phone.

At this example i use char "!" to let my client know when string is at the end.

Maybe its another problem...
I hope somebody can help me.

Here is my Write/Read code:

```
 @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... params) //was strings
     {
         ip = params[0];
        message = params[1];
        port = params[2];


        try
        {
            s = new Socket(ip,Integer.parseInt(port));
            s.setSoTimeout(100000);

            if (s.isConnected())
            {
                dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(message);
                dos.flush();

                is = s.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                //StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                // or of course StringBuffer if you need to be treadsafe
                StringBuilder messageBuffer = new StringBuilder();

                // reads to the end of the stream or till end of message
                while((value = br.read()) != -1) {
                    char c = (char)value;
                    // end?  jump out
                    if (c == endMarker) {
                        break;
                    }
                    // else, add to buffer
                    messageBuffer.append(c);
                }
                // message is complete!
                response = messageBuffer.toString();

                /*
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                response = br.readLine();
                */
            }
            //dos.writeUTF(message);

            //br.close();
            dos.close();
            s.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return response;
    }
```

And the LogCat after i saw the Client was gone:

I dont know if this caused the problem or happend after it:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null

```
2018-11-20 15:34:44.921 3787-3920/? D/SemContextService: 
Service.updateContext() : service = Step Level Monitor
2018-11-20 15:34:44.924 22956-23045/? I/Sensor[0x06]: [0x01] 33
2018-11-20 15:34:44.925 22956-23045/? I/Sensor[0x04]: [0x01] 
1542724446610[0x02] 0[0x03] 2[0x04] 10012
2018-11-20 15:34:45.686 27406-27406/? D/gpsd: CALL_SENTRY(main()): 
GlEngine::OnResourceRelease took 251 ms (from 143759612 to 143759863) 
(logOverhead=0,0,0,0,0,0,0), start: 15:34:45.435
2018-11-20 15:34:45.937 27406-27406/? D/gpsd: CALL_SENTRY(main()): 
GlEngine::OnResourceRequest took 251 ms (from 143759863 to 143760114) 
(logOverhead=0,0,0,0,0,0,0), start: 15:34:45.686
2018-11-20 15:34:45.940 27406-27406/? D/gpsd: CALL_SENTRY(main()): 
GlEngine::ChipData took 506 ms (from 143759611 to 143760117) 
(logOverhead=0,0,0,0,0,0,0), start: 15:34:45.434
2018-11-20 15:34:45.941 27406-27406/? D/gpsd: CALL_SENTRY(main()): 
ProcessEvent took 507 ms (from 143759611 to 143760118) 
(logOverhead=0,0,0,0,0,0,0), start: 15:34:45.434
2018-11-20 15:34:46.161 3787-8916/? D/ConnectivityService: 
filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 1000 networkInfo: [type: WIFI[] - WIFI, 
state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "SocketAppTest", 
failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]
2018-11-20 15:34:46.192 3408-6813/? V/APM_AudioPolicyManager: 
getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;activeStream
2018-11-20 15:34:46.193 3408-6813/? V/APM_AudioPolicyManager: ### active 
stream : 0
2018-11-20 15:34:46.194 3787-8916/? D/AudioService: active stream is 0x0
2018-11-20 15:34:46.196 3408-6813/? V/APM_AudioPolicyManager: 
getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice
2018-11-20 15:34:46.196 3408-6813/? V/APM_AudioPolicyManager: 
getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0
2018-11-20 15:34:46.197 3408-6813/? V/APM_AudioPolicyManager: ### curdevice 
: 2
2018-11-20 15:34:46.202 3787-8916/? W/System.err: 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
2018-11-20 15:34:46.202 3787-8916/? W/System.err:     at 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:570)
2018-11-20 15:34:46.203 3787-8916/? W/System.err:     at b.b.aF(:79)
2018-11-20 15:34:46.203 3787-8916/? W/System.err:     at b.c.aN(:149)
2018-11-20 15:34:46.203 3787-8916/? W/System.err:     at b.n.run(:72)
2018-11-20 15:34:46.203 3787-8916/? W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
2018-11-20 15:34:46.203 3787-8916/? W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
2018-11-20 15:34:46.203 3787-8916/? W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
2018-11-20 15:34:46.203 3787-8916/? W/System.err:     at 
android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2018-11-20 15:34:46.678 12232-12699/? D/ClClient: Not sending keepalive.  
Current connection state=STOPPED
2018-11-20 15:34:46.699 3418-3639/? D/DnsProxyListener: DNSDBG::dns addrinfo 
af 2
2018-11-20 15:34:47.611 3787-8916/? D/SSRM:w: SIOP:: AP = 340, PST = 340 
(W:15), BAT = 313, USB = 318, CHG = 346, CP = 333
2018-11-20 15:34:48.087 4959-4959/? D/io_stats: !@   8,0 r 5038254 276077112 
w 1290028 18962328 d 122047 41066928 f 289127 307003 iot 2157260 1768288 th 
307200 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 63174.392
2018-11-20 15:34:49.339 3787-3909/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Expired : 4
2018-11-20 15:34:49.340 3787-3909/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to 
kernel - T:2 / 20181120T153509, SetElapsed=143783728, nowELAPSED=143763517
2018-11-20 15:34:49.341 3787-3909/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to 
kernel - T:3 / 20181120T153500, SetElapsed=143774177, nowELAPSED=143763518
2018-11-20 15:34:49.342 3787-3909/? V/SamsungAlarmManager: Sending to uid : 
1000 listener=android.app.AlarmManager$ListenerWrapper@fa0b687 
alarm=Alarm{5a2ea2f type 2 when 143763516 android}
2018-11-20 15:34:49.356 3787-4006/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setExact Listener 
(T:2/F:9/AC:false) 20181120T153525 - CU:1000/CP:3787
2018-11-20 15:34:49.501 13308-13308/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread 
pool (1 threads) starved for 155 ms
2018-11-20 15:34:49.632 13308-13308/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread 
pool (1 threads) starved for 129 ms
2018-11-20 15:34:49.649 3787-4015/? D/WifiP2pService: InactiveState143375
2018-11-20 15:34:49.650 3787-4015/? D/WifiP2pService: P2pEnabledState143375
2018-11-20 15:34:49.701 3787-6300/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setExact Listener 
(T:2/F:9/AC:false) 20181120T153450 - CU:1000/CP:3787
2018-11-20 15:34:49.702 3787-6300/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to 
kernel - T:2 / 20181120T153450, SetElapsed=143764875, nowELAPSED=143763879
2018-11-20 15:34:50.698 3787-3909/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Expired : 4
2018-11-20 15:34:50.699 3787-3909/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to 
kernel - T:2 / 20181120T153509, SetElapsed=143783728, nowELAPSED=143764876
2018-11-20 15:34:50.700 3787-3909/? V/SamsungAlarmManager: Sending to uid : 
1000 listener=android.app.AlarmManager$ListenerWrapper@44c69c5 
alarm=Alarm{213f1a type 2 when 143764844 android}
2018-11-20 15:34:50.747 3787-6300/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setExact Listener 
(T:2/F:9/AC:false) 20181120T153452 - CU:1000/CP:3787
2018-11-20 15:34:50.747 3787-6300/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to 
kernel - T:2 / 20181120T153452, SetElapsed=143767063, nowELAPSED=143764924
2018-11-20 15:34:50.753 3787-6300/? D/DhcpClient: Renewed lease: IP address 
172.20.237.2/24 Gateway 172.20.237.1  DNS servers: [ 172.20.237.1 ] Domains  
DHCP server /172.20.237.1 Vendor info null lease 240 seconds
2018-11-20 15:34:50.754 3787-6300/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Cancel Alarm 
calling from uid:1000 pid :3787 / 
listener:android.app.AlarmManager$ListenerWrapper@77dfa4b
2018-11-20 15:34:50.754 3787-4006/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Cancel Alarm 
calling from uid:1000 pid :3787 / 
listener:android.app.AlarmManager$ListenerWrapper@912383c
2018-11-20 15:34:50.758 3787-6300/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to 
kernel - T:2 / 20181120T153500, SetElapsed=143774177, nowELAPSED=143764935
2018-11-20 15:34:50.769 3787-4015/? D/WifiP2pService: InactiveState143375
2018-11-20 15:34:50.769 3787-6300/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setExact Listener 
(T:2/F:9/AC:false) 20181120T153645 - CU:1000/CP:3787
2018-11-20 15:34:50.770 3787-4015/? D/WifiP2pService: P2pEnabledState143375
```

Also i just found this in LogCat:(Maybe the problem?)

```
2018-11-20 16:01:01.546 3384-3384/? E/audit: type=1400 
audit(1542726061.545:3227): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=16998 
comm="Analytics-Norma" name="boot_id" dev="proc" ino=3571102 
scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 
tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G955F_8.0.0_0017 audit_filtered
2018-11-20 16:01:01.549 16998-17153/? E/msgr.BootIdReader: Error reading 
boot_id from procfs
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id (Permission 
denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at X.2MN.a(:372675)
    at X.46q.a(:579709)
    at X.0Hi.A(Unknown Source:26)
    at X.0IH.a(:60614)
    at X.0IH.b(:60638)
    at X.41k.a(:569612)
    at X.1y8.a(:339223)
    at X.1rz.a(:330137)
    at X.0dC.a(:118033)
    at X.0d9.a(:117958)
    at X.0fP.d(:123017)
    at X.0fP.c(:122985)
    at X.0fP.handleMessage(:123035)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2018-11-20 16:01:02.739 16656-16708/? E/Fabric: Settings request failed.
+...
2018-11-20 16:04:25.446 16779-16855/? E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: 
gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: com.enbw.ev, scannerId: 7, 
reportDelayMillis=0
2018-11-20 16:04:25.472 4777-5949/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable 
for task: com.tumblr/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver{u=0 
tag="retryServiceTag" 
trigger=window{start=3429s,end=3610s,earliest=-3609249s,latest=-3609069s} 
requirements=[NET_ANY] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-3612679s 
last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 
client_lib=FIREBASE_JOB_DISPATCHER-1}
2018-11-20 16:04:36.402 3787-4392/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2164 [2018-11-20 
16:04:36.402]
2018-11-20 16:04:39.119 5626-5793/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush 
buffer to file cnt : 1 size : 1Kb duration : 2ms lastUpdatedAfter : 60132 ms 
mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 800
2018-11-20 16:04:55.481 4777-5949/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable 
for task: com.tumblr/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver{u=0 
tag="retryServiceTag" 
trigger=window{start=3429s,end=3610s,earliest=-3609279s,latest=-3609099s} 
requirements=[NET_ANY] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-3612709s 
last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 
client_lib=FIREBASE_JOB_DISPATCHER-1}
2018-11-20 16:04:55.551 16779-16855/? E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: 
gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_START, appName: com.enbw.ev, scannerId: 7, 
reportDelayMillis=0
2018-11-20 16:05:00.596 16779-16855/? E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: 
gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: com.enbw.ev, scannerId: 7, 
reportDelayMillis=0
```

Comment: afaik, reading from socket is blocking operation. Did you try reading it in separate thread? (obviously, did not look into too mcuh)

Comment: which line do u exactly mean? when i try to debug it jumps directly to while...(br.read) and blocks there (i think).

Comment: `read()` will block until it receives a character or until the socket it closed. If your peer sends `endMarker` or closes the socket, then the loop should exit properly. Otherwise it should hang. Your logcats are most likely completely unrelated to the problem. If you require additional help, please post the peer code.